# running callback in different thread

Tags: c#

I have a c# code which captures a fingerprint from a device. The code for capturing is written in c++ dll which returns the image through callback side by side to give live view. But the problem is that the application stops working after some time during capture. This happens because of callback method only. If I comment the code in callback method it works fine. 
I want to know if the callback method can be put in another thread so that the coming images do not get crashed in callback method.
Following is the way how I have called the method.

```
    /* c# code: */

    [DllImport("abc.dll", EntryPoint = "capture", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = false, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    static extern int capture(callback liveImageCallback);

    private delegate void callback(IntPtr img);

    void capture()
    {
      int ret= capture(callBackLiveImage);
    }

    public void callBackLiveImage(IntPtr imgPointer)
    {
      byte[] rawData = new byte[102400];
      Marshal.Copy(imgPointer, rawData, 0, 102400);
    }

    /* c++ code: */

    typedef void (__stdcall * Callback)(unsigned char* img);
    Callback LiveImageHandler;

    void capture(liveCallback)
    {
      LiveImageHandler = liveCallback;
      someMethod();
    }

    someMethod()
    {
      LiveImageHandler(raw_img);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the callback method "contents" is not failing, i.e. Try>>Catch?  Try {  int ret= capture(callBackLiveImage); } catch {   }

Comment: Definitely seems like "XY problem", and in this case I really don't see how running the callback in a different thread would fix the problem. You should focus on figuring out why the callback fails, and fix that.

Comment: Please also describe what "stops working" means exactly. How does it stop working?

Answer (score 1):

You have no error handling in the `callBackLiveImage` method. You're always copying `102400`. My unmanaged sense is seeing an unhandled exception like `AccessViolationException` or such.

Try using a `try`-`catch` statement to catch the exception, and log it:

```
public void callBackLiveImage(IntPtr imgPointer)
{
  try
  {
    byte[] rawData = new byte[102400];
    Marshal.Copy(imgPointer, rawData, 0, 102400);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

Unhandled .NET exceptions in unmanaged code don't really sound like a good idea :)

The specific exception will give you a better idea of what you're dealing with. It might be that the `imgPointer` is `IntPtr.Zero`, or it might be that there's less data than you expected. Also, are you sure the C++ library is taking care of disposing of the memory?